Can one use a passkey to log into Ask Ubuntu?
Now that we can use passkeys with Ubuntu, see Does Ubuntu support passkeys, like Apple, Google and Microsoft do?
Can I use a passkey instead of a password to sign into Ask Ubuntu?
If not, can I use a passkey as a second authentication factor (2FA)?
I can't find a way to either way to use a passkey.
Thanks

Slate from the CM team indicated this is a Support Request, less a Feature Request, and retagged your post, and gave us the general go-ahead to reply on their behalf.

The StackExchange network login system does not have a concept of 2FA.  It was requested long ago for 'global 2FA' here but hasn't seen any movement.
Because there's no real drive or dev timeline to get 2FA on SE logins that're email address and password, it's recommended you bind and connect an external account such as Google, etc. to your SE account.  Then, use the Google account or similar to authenticate with.  You can do the same with a Launchpad account which uses Ubuntu's SSO system to login with.
Passkey support on SE itself is probably not going to happen, so you would need to use one of those third party identity / account systems that does have passkey auth to get it functional here.
